# Module Not Found When Serving Django With WSGI and Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a site which is served in production using WSGI and Apache2. That part was working fine.

However, after making a few changes to adopt the site to the 12-Factor configuration standard (by using `django-environ`), I am getting an error from the `settings.py`, which is found in the Apache error log.

Namely,

```
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764757 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764777 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536]   File "/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764831 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536]    from app_name.settings import env, SITE_ROOT
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764840 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536]   File "/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764885 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536]      import environ
[Tue Aug 15 20:46:08.764901 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 5245:tid 139820676769536]  ImportError: No module named environ
```

In the local environment these files work well. However, it is my suspicion that in the local environment the `wsgi.py` file is not really used, so it does not throw this error.

Now, I have made sure that the `django-environ` module is installed in the virtualenv. I verify it with `pip list`.

Relevant code from `settings.py`:

```
import os

import environ
root = environ.Path(__file__) - 2 # three folder back (/a/b/c/ - 3 = /)
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),) # set default values and casting
environ.Env.read_env() # reading .env file

SITE_ROOT = root()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG') # False if not in os.environ
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`wsgi.py` file:

```
from app_name.settings import env, SITE_ROOT 
LOCAL = env('LOCAL')

# if not in the local development env
if not LOCAL:
    import sys
    import site

    path = SITE_ROOT
    #path='/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx'
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    #Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
    site.addsitedir(env('PYTHON_ENV_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR'))

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app_name.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Why could this be happening and how can I fix it or troubleshoot it?

**EDIT:**
I am posting the WSGI configuration file per request in comments.

```
<IfModule !wsgi_module>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
    #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
    ServerName  www.app_name.store
    ServerAlias app_name.store

    WSGIDaemonProcess app_name display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-env/ python-path=/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIProcessGroup app_name

    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/xxxx/wsgi.py process-group=app_name

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/static/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/media/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where is the ``environ.py`` file located? Have you set the Python module search path in the mod_wsgi configuration? Your ``wsgi.py`` will fail if you haven't as you are trying to import modules before setting the path there.

Comment: It is my understanding that `environ` is located in the `site-packages` within the virtualenv directory. I can post the wsgi config, if that helps.

Comment: The answer has been edited to include the WSGI config.

Comment: From the Python interpreter command line, do ```import environ; print(environ.__file__)``. What do you get?

Comment: It returns `/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/environ/__init__.py`
Now, inside that `environ` directory there is a file called `environ.py`. Does this mean I should be doing `import environ.environ` in my code?

Comment: Is your mod_wsgi compiled for Python 3.5? It you have installed system package for mod_wsgi it could be older version and thus doesn't match virtual environment and will not be found. The mod_wsgi module must be compiled for same Python version.

Comment: How would I find this out? I did the basic `apt-get install` to acquire it.

Comment: Interestingly, if I run the `settings.py` file through interactive Python, it does not give any error. The error only appears on the Apache side when I make a request to the server through browser.

Comment: The mod_wsgi documentation explains how you can check. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: When I run the first WSGI script, I get this back in the browser: `sys.version = '2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
sys.prefix = '/usr'`. Does this mean that the `mod_wsgi` installed is for Python 2.7 and I need to look for that for Python 3.5?

Comment: And the second script that checks search paths returns this: `sys.path = ['/var/www/vhosts/xxxx/xxxx-site', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`.

Comment: Yes, it does mean mod_wsgi is compiled specifically for Python 2.7. You cannot mix versions. Linux distributions aren't good at provided up to date version so I suggest you uninstall mod_wsgi and compile it from source code yourself. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: I see. The only thing i am wondering about at this point is why this showed up just now. I have 2-3 other sites with similar production setups and they work well. However, it is possible that in those sites I never do 'import' of a module that is installed in virtualenv

Comment: After I follow the document, install mod_wsgi through `pip` ad configure it, I get the following in my Apache error log:

Comment: `[Wed Aug 16 15:50:16.602947 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22675:tid 139839746115456] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Wed Aug 16 15:50:17.612254 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22828:tid 140344922654592] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Wed Aug 16 15:50:17.612321 2017] [core:notice] [pid 22828:tid 140344922654592] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: This is accompanied by `Bad Request 400` in the browser. Do you know what may cause this?

Comment: Likely a Django configuration issue, possibly with ``ALLOWED_HOSTS``. Temporarily set ``DEBUG=True`` in Django settings and see if an error is displayed in the browser.

Comment: That's exactly what it was! Thank you for all your help. I have learned a lot through this interaction and looks like the site is up!